# Recycler View accesiblity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, accessibility, talkback

I want accessibility to stop traversing the recycler view items when the next item is not in screen view.

it works as described above when swiping right (next element). If there are no visible recycler view items it goes to the next accessibility element not in the recycler view

It doesn't work as expected when swipping right (previous elemnt). if there are no visible items. recycler view scrolls to the left to reveal more visible item. making it impossible to traverse out of the recycler view since the reclycer view has an "infinite" list of items.

[video reference](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10UlsLAnV29DzZZm_APKHI_wmtEHP2ZPb/view?usp=sharing)

## RECREATE

- activate talk back accessibility
- swipe left or right to traverse the accessibility element tree

## CODE

**build.gradle**

```
//enable view binding
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?\>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00FFFF"
android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
android:focusable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"\>

    <TextView
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    
    
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_blank" />
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NEXT ITEM"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:textColor="@color/teal_700"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginVertical="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/blankView" />

</LinearLayout\>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        with(binding) {
            recyclerView.adapter = Adapter()
            val number: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE / 3 / 2
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(number)
        }
    }
}

class Adapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {

    val noOfItems = 3

    class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemBlankBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(ItemBlankBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val index = position % noOfItems
        with(holder.binding) {
            textView.text = index.toString()
            root.contentDescription = "$index"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Headings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#headings_within_text) are your friend here. If you ensure that there is a heading below the `recylerview` for your content, folks can change their granularity to headings (three finger horizontal swipe) and then use the granularity (swipe up and down) to skip over.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:accessibilityHeading="true"
    android:text="@string/my_heading_before_recycler_view"
    />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:accessibilityHeading="true"
    android:text="@string/my_heading_after_recycler_view"
    />
```

I [published a blog on Android headings](https://qbalsdon.github.io/accessibility,/testing,/unit/tests,/heading/2023/03/13/accessibility-headings.html) today, but if you want the quick way, I uploaded a [video for you demonstrating how to use headings](https://youtube.com/shorts/kfXPXyhy3CE?feature=share)

Keep in mind headings are post [API 28](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setAccessibilityHeading(boolean)) and if you support less, you may want to create some kind of skip action - you can add an [accessibility action](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#accessibility-actions) to the 'recyclerview' to skip over the list and focus on the next element.

Also keep in mind users probably can use [explore by touch](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006598?hl=en-GB) to get over the `recyclerview` anyway.

Neither of these solutions deal with motor impairment or use Switch Access, but to be honest the action example is robust enough to work, it would require Google to surface actions to those users - so I don't think that is on the developer.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this doesn't answer my question. As the video show. when swiping right the accessibility focus leaves the recylcerview item if the next item is out of screen bounds. i want to do this also when swiping left.

Comment: My apologies - you're absolutely right - I missed the point. I've managed to reproduce the problem, but it's only when the number of elements is set to `Int.MAX_VALUE`, correct? You only get this behaviour when the number is greater than 22330841, if it's 22330841 or less I think you get the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It seems,what for this you should override ACCESSIBILITY_ACTION_SCROLL_(BACKWARD_FORWARD) in special delegate:

```
mList.setAccessibilityDelegateCompat(new RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate(mList) {
                        @Override
            public boolean performAccessibilityAction(@NonNull View host, int action, @Nullable Bundle args) {
                //for details see sources (https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.java?q=RecyclerView) class LayoutManager (or something so).
                if((action==AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_SCROLL_BACKWARD ||action==AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD) &&host instanceof RecyclerView) {
...
}
}
});
```

also please pay attention on accessibility action AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_SHOW_ON_SCREEN